# can't edit integer with .noinit attribute on STM32L476 with custom linker file

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller, linker-scripts, stm32cubeide

I'm doing my first attempt working with linker files. In the end i want to have a variable that keeps it's value after reset. I'm working with an STM32L476.

To achieve this i modified the Linker files: STM32L476JGYX_FLASH.ld and STM32L476JGYX_RAM.ld to include a partition called NOINT.

```
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 96K
  RAM2    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x10000000,   LENGTH = 32K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 1024K -0x100 
  NOINIT (rwx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000 + 1024K - 0x100, LENGTH = 0x100
}


/* Sections */
SECTIONS
{
...
 
     /* Global data not cleared after reset.  */
    .noinit (NOLOAD): {
        KEEP(*(*.noinit*))
    } > NOINIT
...
```

In the main.c i initialize the variable reset_count as a global variable.

```
__attribute__((section(".noinit")))  volatile uint32_t reset_count = 0;
```

The =0 part is just for simplification. I actually want to set reset_count to zero somewhere in a function.

When i run the program and step through the initialization i would expect to see the value of reset_count as 0. But somehow i always get 0xFFFFFFFF. It seems like i can't edit the reset_count variable. Can anybody tell me how i can make this variable editable?

[image: Debugger view]

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the question whether you want to have a variable that keeps its value when power is removed, or just while power stays on but hardware reset is pulsed.

If you want something that keeps its value when power is removed, then your linker script is ok to put the block in flash memory, but you need to use the functions `HAL_FLASH_Program` etc. to write to it, you can't just make an assignment.  In addition, you could simplify the linker script by instead of creating the `NOINIT` output region, just putting `>FLASH`.

If you want a variable that just persists across reset wile power stays up then you need to put the variable into SRAM not FLASH, for example like this:

```
.noinit (NOLOAD) :
{
    *(.noinit*)
}
> RAM2
```

Note that you don't need to use `KEEP` unless you want to link a section that is unreferenced, which will not be the case if you actually use the variables, and you don't need another `*` immediately before `.noinit` unless you section names don't start with a `.`, which they should.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to write to the flash memory as simply as that. If you use ST HAL, there is a flash module that provides `HAL_FLASH_Program()` function.

Alternatively, if the data you are trying to store is 128 bytes or less and you have an RTC backup battery, you can use the RTC backup registers (RTC_BKPxR) to store your data.